# $\log_{2} \frac{1-ab}{a + b} = 2ab + a + b -3$. Find min of $(a +b)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponentiation

> **Problem**: $a$, $b$ are positive real numbers and $\log_{2} \frac{1-ab}{a + b} = 2ab + a + b -3$. Find the minimum value of $P = a + b$

I reached this point and had no idea how to proceed. Please advise: $2^{2(1-ab) + 1}(1 - ab) = 2^{a + b}(a + b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take notations

$$S=a+b, \ \ P=ab$$

keeping in mind the classical inequality (Arith. Mean vs. Geom. Mean)

$$S \ge 2\sqrt{P}\tag{1}$$

With these notations, your relationship, which can be written :

$$8(1-ab)=2^{a+b+2ab}(a+b)$$

becomes :

$$8(1-P)=2^{S+2P}S$$

(1) implies :

$$8(1-P) \ge 2^{2\sqrt{P}+2P}2 \sqrt{P}$$

$$\underbrace{4(1-P)}_{f(P)} \ge \underbrace{4^{\sqrt{P}+P}\sqrt{P}}_{g(P)}\tag{2}$$

$f$ is decreasing with $f(0)=4,f(1)=0$, $g$ is increasing with $g(0)=0,g(1)=16$ as can be seen on the following graphical representation

[image]

Therefore their curves have a unique intersection point.

In fact the abscissa $P_0$ of this point is the unique positive root $P_0$ of equation :

$$P+\sqrt{P}=1\tag{3}$$

(check it by plugging the LHS of (3) in (2)).

Equation (3) above can be solved explicitly because, setting $p=\sqrt{P}$, it becomes a quadratic equation, giving :

$$P_0=\left(\tfrac12(\sqrt{5}-1)\right)^2=\tfrac12(3-\sqrt{5}) \approx 0.381966\tag{4}$$

In this way, the **maximal** value of $P$ is $P_0$.

From there, the **minimal** value of $S$ is obtained by using the result saying that for a fixed value of the sum of two numbers, their product is maximal when they are equal.

Indeed, consider a fixed value of S :

- For example if $S=2$, is it possible to have a corresponding P ? The answer is no because $P$ is maximum when $a=b$ ; in this case we would have $a=b=1$ giving $P=1$ which is impossible.
- Can we have $S=1$ ? Now, the answer is yes because it suffices to take $a=b=\tfrac12$ giving
  $P=ab=\frac14$ which is possible, etc.

One has understood with these examples that the optimal choice leading to a minimal $P$ is to take :

$$a=b=\tfrac12S \ \text{in such a way that} \ P:=ab=P_0$$ which means $$a=\sqrt{P_0} \ \iff \ S=2a=2\sqrt{P_0}$$

I.e., the optimal/minimal $S$ is (see (4)) :

$$S=S_0=\sqrt{5}-1$$

Comment: This is not complete IMO, how do you know the sum attains its minimum value only when $P = P_0$?

Comment: @D S I understand your objection. One must have a reasoning like this : consider a fixed value of $S$ such as $2$. Is it possible  to have a corresponding $P$ : answer no because $P$ is maximum when $a=b$ and in this case $a=b=1$ giving $P=1$ which is impossible. Can we have $S=1$ ? answer yes because it suffices to take $a=b=\tfrac12$ and in this case $P=\tfrac14$ is possible, etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I'm a bit lost after the point about $P_0$. However, when I saw you mention AM-GM, I stopped reading further and tried to solve it myself the following way: I rewrote the original equation as $f(P) = g(S)$. Since $P < 1$, I was able to argue that $f(\frac{S^2}{4}) \leq f(P)$, so $f(\frac{S^2}{4}) \leq g(S).$ Bring everything to one side and it became $h(S) \geq 0.$ Then I found that $h'(S) > 0,$ so $S \geq S_0$ with $h(S_0) = 0$, and $S_0 = -1 + \sqrt{5}$. However, I had to guess $S_0$ using a calculator and argued it backward instead of explicitly finding $S_0$ algebraically.

Comment: The final equation I had to guess $S_0$ is $S*2^{\frac{S^2}{2} + S - 1} - 4 + S^2 = 0$, but I don't know how to solve it myself.

Comment: As $S_0=-1+\sqrt{5} \implies  S_0^2=6-2\sqrt{5} \implies  \frac12S_0^2=3-\sqrt{5}$ we can say $\frac12S_0^2=S_0+4 \iff  S_0^2=2S_0+8$. Now replace $S_0^2$ by this expression into your equation : you should get identical LHS and RHS.

Comment: I have completed my answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! Since $\sqrt{P_0} = \frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{5} - 1)$, isn't it that $S = 2\sqrt{P} = \sqrt{5} - 1$?

Comment: You are perfectly right. I correct the error.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much for your help!